# Why is my Extrude Along Normals acting like Extrude Along Individual Faces?

Tags: faces, extrude

I am trying to Extrude Along Normals, but I am getting Extrude Along Individual faces instead:

My Pivot Point is set to Median.
Why is it acting like this?

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. It looks like you have duplicate vertices. Can you try remove them with `A` then `M` *> Merge By Distance*